# iPhone iOS what's the correct way to instantiate static NSString cell reuse identifiers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios6, uicollectionview

in iOS5 and 6, I can retrieve cells for a table view or collection view using their reuse identifiers (registered in the storyboard). The majority of the code samples I see define a static NSString identifier within the cellForItemAtIndexPath method. This seems counter-intuitive to me - does the reuse identifier gets re-assigned each time this method is called?

In my own code, I pull the static assignment outside the method call to ensure that it is only done once.

A silly question, **but how does one instantiate a static NSString only once?**

```
//should I define it here, outside the method?
static NSString *kCellID = @"kCellID";

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
//or should I define it here, within the method?
static NSString *kCellID = @"kCellID";


//retrieve cell using the identifier
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no particular benefit in making static itself other than readability in terms ,since the identifier itself is a constant string.Making it global makes it available everywhere and that memory is created and managed as constant chunk from the beginning otherwise it is created once at the time it is created inside the code.No visible difference in any

Answer (score 1):

A static variable inside a function is initialised the first time the function is executed, whereas a global static will be initialised at startup.

The local static is slightly less efficient, but is neater in terms of encapsulation.